# Validity of my proof about $A \preceq B$ if and only if $\#A \le \#B$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'd like to know if my proof of the next theorem is correct or maybe need some adjustments to be correct.

**Definition:** Let $A,B$ be sets. We write $A\preceq B\iff$ there exists an injection $A\to B$.

**Theorem:** Let $A, B$ be finite sets. Then, $A \preceq B$ if and only if $\#A \le \#B$.

**Proof:**

($\Rightarrow$)
Let $\varphi(n)$ be the statement "B is a set of size $\,n\,$ and $A \preceq B \rightarrow \#A \le n$."

$$S = \left\{\,n\in \omega:\varphi(n)\, \right\}.$$

For $n = 0\,$, B is the empty set, and the only injection is to itself. So, clearly $0 \in S.$ Assume $n \in S $ we need to show that $n^{+} \in S$.

Suppose  $ \#B =n^{+}$ and $\,f: A \rightarrow B\,$ is an injective map. We choose an element $b\in B$.

If $\,b \in f[A] $ therefore $ f(a) = b\,$ for a unique $a\in A$. Let $A^{*} = A-\left\{a \right\}$ and $\,B^{*} = B -\left\{b \right\}$. We define the function $g: A^{*} \rightarrow B^{*}$ to be the restriction of $f$ in $A^{*}$, i.e., $\,g = f\restriction_{A^{*}}$. Then, $g\,$ is a one-to-one function and by our inductive hypothesis $\#A^{*} \le \#B^{*}.$ But since $\#A^{*} = \#A-1\,$ and $\#B^{*} = n$. Then, $\#A-1 \le \ n \rightarrow \#A \le n^{+} .$

If $b \notin f[A]$. Let $B^{*} = B-\left\{b \right\}$. Where $f: A \rightarrow B^{*}$ is a one-to-one function, and by inductive hypothesis $\#A \le \#B^{*}.$ But since $\#B^{*} = \#B-1 = n$. Then, $\#A \le n^{+} $.

Hence $n^{+} \in S$ which close the induction.

($\Leftarrow$) We need to show that $\#A \le \#B$ implies the existence of an injective map $f: A\rightarrow B$.

For $\#B = 0\,$, that means $\#A = 0$. And clearly $f: \emptyset \rightarrow \emptyset $ is an injection. Suppose our claims holds for n, we need to show that also holds for $n^{+}$.

For $\# B = n^{+}$, as $n^{+} \not = 0\,$ the set is nonempty, so  there exist an element $b \in B$. Let $B^{*} = B -\left\{b \right\}$, then we have that $\#B^{*} = n$.

If $\#A \le \#B^{*}$ by our inductive hypothesis, there exist a injective map $g : A \rightarrow B^{*}$. Let $i_{ B^{*} \rightarrow B}$ be the inclusion map, i.e., $i_{ B^{*} \rightarrow B}: B^{*} \rightarrow B : j \mapsto j\,$, which is an injection. Therefore, the composition $\, i_{ B^{*} \rightarrow B} \circ g: A \rightarrow B\,$, is an injection as desired.

If $\, \#A \not\le \#B^{*}$ but $ \#A \le \#B $, i.e., $ \#A = n^{+}$. We set $A^{*} = A-\left\{a \right\}$. Then $\#A^{*}\le \#B^{*}$ and by the inductive hypothesis there exist an injective map $h': A^{*} \rightarrow B^{*}$. We can define the function $h: A \rightarrow B$, by adding the ordered pair $ \langle a, b \rangle $ to the function $h'$. That is, $h: = h' \cup \left\{\,  \langle a, b \rangle  \, \right\}$ (as $ \langle a, b \rangle $ is a genuine extra element, the map $h$ is one-to-one).  $\;\;\ \Box$

As always thanks in advance.

Comment: What does $\preceq$ mean?

Comment: @AsafKaragila From what I read, it means there exists an injective function $A\to B$.

Comment: You should also define $\le$. I assume that it's the transitive closure of the successor function?

Comment: @dfeuer Since the sets are finite, it means usual inequality, I take it.

Comment: @PeterTamaroff: what is usual inequality? It can be *defined* by $m\le n \iff m\preceq n$, or it can be defined set-theorishly as the transitive closure of the successor function, or arithmetically with Peano arithmetic (including addition) or probably some other ways too.

Comment: @dfeuerm, In the book define t $n \le m$ to be $ n\in m \vee n = m$

Comment: @AsafKaragila $\preceq$ means as Peter said: there exist an injection between the set A and B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument is okay as far as it goes, but the proof of $(\Leftarrow)$ is incomplete. You’ve shown that if $\#A\le\#B^*$, then there’s an injection from $A$ to $B$, but you’ve not covered the case in which $\#A\le\#B$ but $\#A\not\le\#B^*$. Of course in that case $\#A=n^+$, and there’s a very easy argument to show that there’s an injection from $A$ to $B$, but you do have to cover that case.

Comment: Thanks as always for helping me. I just changed that part of the proof.

Comment: @Jose: You’re welcome. What you’ve done works, but there’s an even easier way. If $\#A=n^+=\#B$, there are bijections $f:A\to n^+$ and $g:B\to n+^$, and $g^{-1}\circ f$ is then a bijection from $A$ to $B$.